# Accessing to server response text when the request is sent via form.submit method?

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs4, form-submit

Please consider the following code. I need to access "raw response text" in failure/success method. How should I achieve that?

```
myFormPanel.getForm().submit({
    url: 'updateConsignment.php',
    success: function(form, action) {
       Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
    },
    failure: function(form, action) {
        switch (action.failureType) {
            case Ext.form.action.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Form fields may not be submitted with invalid values');
                break;
            case Ext.form.action.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Ajax communication failed');
                break;
            case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID:
               Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myFormPanel.getForm().submit({
    url: 'updateConsignment.php',
    success: function(form, action) {
       console.log(action.result);
       Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
    },
    failure: function(form, action) {
        console.log(action.result);
        switch (action.failureType) {
            case Ext.form.action.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Form fields may not be submitted with invalid values');
                break;
            case Ext.form.action.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Ajax communication failed');
                break;
            case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID:
               Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
       }
    }
});
```

`action.result` should contain the response from the server.

You can get the RAW response by using `action.response` as described [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Submit-property-response)

Comment: Thanks, while the server return a 400 response with some text in the response body, the action.response is null. I want to alert any server exception message.

Comment: have you tried the `action.failureType` property to see what that contains